# C Macro with _Pragma fails to compile

Tags: c, gcc, macros, gcc12

I'm trying to define a macro to return the result of a range check which works on signed and unsigned types. However, because I am compiling with `-Wextra` which includes [`-Wtype-limits`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wtype-limits), I want to ignore `-Wtype-limits` just for this macro. Unfortunately, this:

```c
#define IN_RANGE(v, min, max) \
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wtype-limits\"") \
    ( (((v) < (max)) && ((v) > (min))) ? true : false ) \
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")
```

Fails to compile (because I'm *also* using `-Werror`) with:

```bash
... error: expected expression before '#pragma'
[build]    40 | _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
[build]       | ^~~~~~~
```

Edit: here's a complete example.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define IN_RANGE(v, min, max) \
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wtype-limits\"") \
    ( (((v) < (max)) && ((v) > (min))) ? true : false ) \
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")

const uint32_t MIN_NUM = 0;
const uint32_t MAX_NUM = 10;

int main() {
  printf("%s", IN_RANGE(8, MIN_NUM, MAX_NUM) ? "OK": "FAIL");
  return 0;
}
```

Fails with (on gcc 9):

```bash
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra example.c
example.c: In function ‘main’:
example.c:14:1: error: expected expression before ‘#pragma’
   14 |   printf("%s", IN_RANGE(8, MIN_NUM, MAX_NUM) ? "OK": "FAIL");
      | ^ ~
```

Comment: What is the minimum full source code which reproduces this problem? What is the full error message (without filters)?

Comment: Maybe you call the macro in a bad place? Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: The ternary operator really isn't needed.  If the condition evaluates to true, you return true; if it evaluates to false, you return false.  That's awfully similar to just using the condition without the ternary operator.  There might just be an `int` to `bool` conversion — but that could be a cast.

Comment: added a complete example

Comment: For the record, Clang compiles this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given some experimentation, it seems that you can't just embed the `_Pragma()` operator in the middle of an expression.  In effect, it needs to be used where a statement can be used.

This code compiles, and AFAICT it is because there's a complete statement sandwiched between the `_Pragma()` operators:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define IN_RANGE2(r, v, min, max) \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wtype-limits\"") \
        ((r) = (((v) < (max)) && ((v) > (min)))); \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")

int main(void)
{
    int x = 10;
    bool y;
    IN_RANGE2(y, x, -9, +9);

    printf("%d\n", y);

    return 0;
}
```

Note the semicolon before the third `_Pragma()` operator.  Without that, I was getting `expected ‘;’ before ‘#pragma’` (as an error since I too compile with `-Werror`).

I've also simplified the conditional so it doesn't use the ternary operator, as I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75480114/c-macro-with-pragma-fails-to-compile#comment133175570_75480114).

The relevant section of the standard is [§6.10.9 Pragma operator](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.9).  It says:

> A unary operator expression of the form:
>
> ```
> _Pragma ( string-literal )
> ```
>
> is processed as follows: The string literal is destringized by deleting any encoding prefix, deleting the leading and trailing double-quotes, replacing each escape sequence `\"` by a double-quote, and replacing each escape sequence `\\` by a single backslash. The resulting sequence of characters is processed through translation phase 3 to produce preprocessing tokens that are executed as if they were the *pp-tokens* in a pragma directive. The original four preprocessing tokens in the unary operator expression are removed.

Think about what the code expands to in your example:

```
int main(void)
{
  printf("%s", IN_RANGE(8, MIN_NUM, MAX_NUM) ? "OK": "FAIL");
  return 0;
}
```

is approximately equivalent to:

```
/* SO 7548-0114 */
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const uint32_t MIN_NUM = 0;
const uint32_t MAX_NUM = 10;

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s",
    #pragma GCC diagnostic push
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wtype-limits"
    ((((8) < (MAX_NUM)) || (8) > (MIN_NUM)) ? true : false)
    #pragma GCC diagnostic push
    ? "OK": "FAIL");
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't compile.  It produces the error:

```
pragma67.c: In function ‘main’:
pragma67.c:12:11: error: expected expression before ‘#pragma’
   12 |   #pragma GCC diagnostic push
      |           ^~~
```

Line 12 is the first `#pragma` directive.

I'm not totally convinced that this is what the standard mandates, but it is what I get from GCC 11.2.0.

However, when I compile with Apple's Clang (`Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)`), both versions of the code I show compile OK.  Thus, there is a discrepancy in the interpretation of the standard between these two major C compilers.

And, indeed, when I compile with Clang, your original code compiles cleanly.  You can probably make a case out for a bug report to the GCC team.  However, if you're going to write portable code, you'll need to accept the limitations imposed by GCC for a few years yet (though that depends on your portability requirements).